# To whom the properties belong?

Tags: rational-numbers

There are many properties like the closure property, commutative property, associative property, distributive property.

> ***Now my question is are these the properties of numbers or operations.***

**Should I say the closure property of integers or addition.**

To me it looks like they are the properties of Operations because for e.g. integers can be closed under addition but not under division.

Still I am a little bit confused.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: We have a [Mathematical structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) made of numbers (the objects) and operations on them. So, yes, the closure property is a property of the operation defined on the objects of the structure.

Comment: It is "the closure property of integers under addition".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sounds good but **Why?**

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I am confused again see Mauro 's comment.

Comment: It can't be just "the closure property of addition" because then the question arises "addition of what?". Likewise, it cannot just be "closure property of integers" because question arises "do what with integers?".

Comment: There is a door in a room. Does the door belong to the room or to the house?

Comment: In other words it's property of both.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Nice analogy.